# Refresh windows services through cmd

Tags: services, windows-server-2003, cmd.exe

I am trying to refresh the state of a specific service on windows server 2003.

I tried using `refresh <service instance>` but if I run this I get this error:

```
'refresh' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Can you guys please assist me as to how do I run this command in cmd?

Comment: Alternative commands: `sc stop <service> & sc start <service>`

Answer (score 1):

<s>Use [`Services.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885782.aspx) for this.</s>

```
 services refresh <service instance>
```

### Update

You can use the [`Sc`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754599.aspx) utility(from *Windows*).

> Communicates with the Service Controller and installed services. The
>   SC.exe program provides capabilities similar to those provided in
>   Services in the Control Panel.

Works on:

> `Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2003 R2, Windows Server 2003 with SP1, Windows Server 2003 with SP2, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2012, Windows Vista`

Comment: The linked article refers to Windows CE 5.0.

Comment: @and31415 Looks now. =)